# How to I modify color in an SVG in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm looking to modify the color of an SVG. I'm currently attempting to modify the file directly however with no luck. I'm using react and here is the code for the SVG I'm trying to edit.

```
import * as React from "react";

const ReduceCosts: React.FC = (props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => {
  return (
    <svg
      width="55px"
      height="65px"
      viewBox="0 0 53 45"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <title>{"Reduce Costs Icon@1x"}</title>
      <defs>
        <filter id="prefix__a">
          <feColorMatrix
            in="SourceGraphic"
            values="0 0 0 0 0.870588 0 0 0 0 0.172549 0 0 0 0 0.058824 0 0 0 1.000000 0"
          />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g
        transform="translate(1 -4)"
        filter="url(#prefix__a)"
        fill="none"
        fillRule="evenodd"
      >
        <g stroke="#000" fill="#000">
          <path d="M43.822 28.67c-.3-.193-.58-.413-.84-.656-.93-.893-1.36-1.932-1.092-2.657.204-.562.525-.866.887-.903h.079c.473.035.9.3 1.139.709.62 1.06.457 2.152-.173 3.522v-.015zm4.625 1.05a.93.93 0 00-1.218-.494h0a3.001 3.001 0 01-1.68.157c.73-1.616 1.097-3.375.047-5.15a3.23 3.23 0 00-2.992-1.612 2.957 2.957 0 00-2.463 2.1c-.525 1.44.069 3.22 1.575 4.641a7.47 7.47 0 001.229.946 2.723 2.723 0 01-1.512 1.05c-.714.152-1.528-.1-2.415-.751a14.01 14.01 0 00-4.898-7.518.929.929 0 10-1.176 1.433c2.913 2.43 4.536 5.623 4.536 9.015 0 3.759-2.032 7.312-5.57 9.759a.92.92 0 00-.384.945l1.14 5.712h-5.077a.4.4 0 01-.336-.23l-.64-3.061a.924.924 0 00-1.093-.714c-2.814.51-5.696.51-8.51 0a.924.924 0 00-1.092.714l-.64 3.013a.397.397 0 01-.337.23H9.87l1.134-5.276a.934.934 0 00-.635-1.086 7.26 7.26 0 01-4.515-4.347.925.925 0 00-.856-.578h-2.51a3.465 3.465 0 01-.63-.036v-5.864c0-.756.394-.756.588-.756h1.959a.93.93 0 00.908-.725 11.547 11.547 0 012.662-5.124.941.941 0 00.23-.688c-.178-2.247-1.018-3.633-1.91-5.103l-.231-.383c2.966-.126 5.376.525 7.014 1.88a.93.93 0 00.934.152 18.388 18.388 0 013.638-.96.93.93 0 10-.304-1.833 21.01 21.01 0 00-3.491.892c-1.717-1.233-4.641-2.41-9.45-1.848a.934.934 0 00-.714 1.36c.336.64.672 1.187.997 1.722.777 1.286 1.407 2.32 1.607 3.911A13.284 13.284 0 003.67 30.12H2.446C.982 30.119 0 31.169 0 32.718v5.827c0 1.974 1.869 1.974 2.488 1.974h1.917a9.087 9.087 0 004.61 4.568L8.01 49.748c-.108.5.016 1.02.336 1.418.36.428.891.67 1.45.661l5.144-.03a2.205 2.205 0 002.142-1.697l.447-2.157c2.464.35 4.965.35 7.428 0l.452 2.142a2.221 2.221 0 002.147 1.695l5.14.032a1.842 1.842 0 001.438-.651 1.7 1.7 0 00.347-1.413l-1.05-5.28c3.77-2.783 5.901-6.731 5.901-10.931v-.599a4.163 4.163 0 002.488.257 4.663 4.663 0 002.846-2.1 4.89 4.89 0 003.292-.147.935.935 0 00.489-1.228h-.001z" />
          <path d="M27.752 6.384a6.872 6.872 0 11-6.873 6.872v-.005a6.878 6.878 0 016.873-6.873v.006zm0 15.603a8.73 8.73 0 10-8.731-8.736 8.741 8.741 0 008.73 8.736h0z" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default React.memo(ReduceCosts);
```

I understand that I should be changing the fill and/or stroke value. However I can't manage to adjust the color of this thing which is showing orange, although the stroke and fill values are currently #000. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like it's using a filter to change the hue. You need that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG you're using uses [`feColorMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix) which changes the hue of the color.

I removed that for you below and added the orange into the stroke and fill color.

```html
<svg
  width="55px"
  height="65px"
  viewBox="0 0 53 45"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <title>Something</title>
  <g
    transform="translate(1 -4)"
    fill="none"
    fillRule="evenodd"
  >
    <g stroke="#F07345" fill="#F07345">
      <path d="M43.822 28.67c-.3-.193-.58-.413-.84-.656-.93-.893-1.36-1.932-1.092-2.657.204-.562.525-.866.887-.903h.079c.473.035.9.3 1.139.709.62 1.06.457 2.152-.173 3.522v-.015zm4.625 1.05a.93.93 0 00-1.218-.494h0a3.001 3.001 0 01-1.68.157c.73-1.616 1.097-3.375.047-5.15a3.23 3.23 0 00-2.992-1.612 2.957 2.957 0 00-2.463 2.1c-.525 1.44.069 3.22 1.575 4.641a7.47 7.47 0 001.229.946 2.723 2.723 0 01-1.512 1.05c-.714.152-1.528-.1-2.415-.751a14.01 14.01 0 00-4.898-7.518.929.929 0 10-1.176 1.433c2.913 2.43 4.536 5.623 4.536 9.015 0 3.759-2.032 7.312-5.57 9.759a.92.92 0 00-.384.945l1.14 5.712h-5.077a.4.4 0 01-.336-.23l-.64-3.061a.924.924 0 00-1.093-.714c-2.814.51-5.696.51-8.51 0a.924.924 0 00-1.092.714l-.64 3.013a.397.397 0 01-.337.23H9.87l1.134-5.276a.934.934 0 00-.635-1.086 7.26 7.26 0 01-4.515-4.347.925.925 0 00-.856-.578h-2.51a3.465 3.465 0 01-.63-.036v-5.864c0-.756.394-.756.588-.756h1.959a.93.93 0 00.908-.725 11.547 11.547 0 012.662-5.124.941.941 0 00.23-.688c-.178-2.247-1.018-3.633-1.91-5.103l-.231-.383c2.966-.126 5.376.525 7.014 1.88a.93.93 0 00.934.152 18.388 18.388 0 013.638-.96.93.93 0 10-.304-1.833 21.01 21.01 0 00-3.491.892c-1.717-1.233-4.641-2.41-9.45-1.848a.934.934 0 00-.714 1.36c.336.64.672 1.187.997 1.722.777 1.286 1.407 2.32 1.607 3.911A13.284 13.284 0 003.67 30.12H2.446C.982 30.119 0 31.169 0 32.718v5.827c0 1.974 1.869 1.974 2.488 1.974h1.917a9.087 9.087 0 004.61 4.568L8.01 49.748c-.108.5.016 1.02.336 1.418.36.428.891.67 1.45.661l5.144-.03a2.205 2.205 0 002.142-1.697l.447-2.157c2.464.35 4.965.35 7.428 0l.452 2.142a2.221 2.221 0 002.147 1.695l5.14.032a1.842 1.842 0 001.438-.651 1.7 1.7 0 00.347-1.413l-1.05-5.28c3.77-2.783 5.901-6.731 5.901-10.931v-.599a4.163 4.163 0 002.488.257 4.663 4.663 0 002.846-2.1 4.89 4.89 0 003.292-.147.935.935 0 00.489-1.228h-.001z" />
      <path d="M27.752 6.384a6.872 6.872 0 11-6.873 6.872v-.005a6.878 6.878 0 016.873-6.873v.006zm0 15.603a8.73 8.73 0 10-8.731-8.736 8.741 8.741 0 008.73 8.736h0z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now you can use that to change the color more direclty

```html
<svg
  width="55px"
  height="65px"
  viewBox="0 0 53 45"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <title>Something</title>
  <g
    transform="translate(1 -4)"
    fill="none"
    fillRule="evenodd"
  >
    <g stroke="blue" fill="blue">
      <path d="M43.822 28.67c-.3-.193-.58-.413-.84-.656-.93-.893-1.36-1.932-1.092-2.657.204-.562.525-.866.887-.903h.079c.473.035.9.3 1.139.709.62 1.06.457 2.152-.173 3.522v-.015zm4.625 1.05a.93.93 0 00-1.218-.494h0a3.001 3.001 0 01-1.68.157c.73-1.616 1.097-3.375.047-5.15a3.23 3.23 0 00-2.992-1.612 2.957 2.957 0 00-2.463 2.1c-.525 1.44.069 3.22 1.575 4.641a7.47 7.47 0 001.229.946 2.723 2.723 0 01-1.512 1.05c-.714.152-1.528-.1-2.415-.751a14.01 14.01 0 00-4.898-7.518.929.929 0 10-1.176 1.433c2.913 2.43 4.536 5.623 4.536 9.015 0 3.759-2.032 7.312-5.57 9.759a.92.92 0 00-.384.945l1.14 5.712h-5.077a.4.4 0 01-.336-.23l-.64-3.061a.924.924 0 00-1.093-.714c-2.814.51-5.696.51-8.51 0a.924.924 0 00-1.092.714l-.64 3.013a.397.397 0 01-.337.23H9.87l1.134-5.276a.934.934 0 00-.635-1.086 7.26 7.26 0 01-4.515-4.347.925.925 0 00-.856-.578h-2.51a3.465 3.465 0 01-.63-.036v-5.864c0-.756.394-.756.588-.756h1.959a.93.93 0 00.908-.725 11.547 11.547 0 012.662-5.124.941.941 0 00.23-.688c-.178-2.247-1.018-3.633-1.91-5.103l-.231-.383c2.966-.126 5.376.525 7.014 1.88a.93.93 0 00.934.152 18.388 18.388 0 013.638-.96.93.93 0 10-.304-1.833 21.01 21.01 0 00-3.491.892c-1.717-1.233-4.641-2.41-9.45-1.848a.934.934 0 00-.714 1.36c.336.64.672 1.187.997 1.722.777 1.286 1.407 2.32 1.607 3.911A13.284 13.284 0 003.67 30.12H2.446C.982 30.119 0 31.169 0 32.718v5.827c0 1.974 1.869 1.974 2.488 1.974h1.917a9.087 9.087 0 004.61 4.568L8.01 49.748c-.108.5.016 1.02.336 1.418.36.428.891.67 1.45.661l5.144-.03a2.205 2.205 0 002.142-1.697l.447-2.157c2.464.35 4.965.35 7.428 0l.452 2.142a2.221 2.221 0 002.147 1.695l5.14.032a1.842 1.842 0 001.438-.651 1.7 1.7 0 00.347-1.413l-1.05-5.28c3.77-2.783 5.901-6.731 5.901-10.931v-.599a4.163 4.163 0 002.488.257 4.663 4.663 0 002.846-2.1 4.89 4.89 0 003.292-.147.935.935 0 00.489-1.228h-.001z" />
      <path d="M27.752 6.384a6.872 6.872 0 11-6.873 6.872v-.005a6.878 6.878 0 016.873-6.873v.006zm0 15.603a8.73 8.73 0 10-8.731-8.736 8.741 8.741 0 008.73 8.736h0z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

So your react component would look like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

const ReduceCosts: React.FC = (props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => {
  return (
    <svg
      width="55px"
      height="65px"
      viewBox="0 0 53 45"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      {...props}
    >
      <title>{"Reduce Costs Icon@1x"}</title>
      <g
        transform="translate(1 -4)"
        fill="none"
        fillRule="evenodd"
      >
        <g stroke="#000" fill="#000">
          <path d="M43.822 28.67c-.3-.193-.58-.413-.84-.656-.93-.893-1.36-1.932-1.092-2.657.204-.562.525-.866.887-.903h.079c.473.035.9.3 1.139.709.62 1.06.457 2.152-.173 3.522v-.015zm4.625 1.05a.93.93 0 00-1.218-.494h0a3.001 3.001 0 01-1.68.157c.73-1.616 1.097-3.375.047-5.15a3.23 3.23 0 00-2.992-1.612 2.957 2.957 0 00-2.463 2.1c-.525 1.44.069 3.22 1.575 4.641a7.47 7.47 0 001.229.946 2.723 2.723 0 01-1.512 1.05c-.714.152-1.528-.1-2.415-.751a14.01 14.01 0 00-4.898-7.518.929.929 0 10-1.176 1.433c2.913 2.43 4.536 5.623 4.536 9.015 0 3.759-2.032 7.312-5.57 9.759a.92.92 0 00-.384.945l1.14 5.712h-5.077a.4.4 0 01-.336-.23l-.64-3.061a.924.924 0 00-1.093-.714c-2.814.51-5.696.51-8.51 0a.924.924 0 00-1.092.714l-.64 3.013a.397.397 0 01-.337.23H9.87l1.134-5.276a.934.934 0 00-.635-1.086 7.26 7.26 0 01-4.515-4.347.925.925 0 00-.856-.578h-2.51a3.465 3.465 0 01-.63-.036v-5.864c0-.756.394-.756.588-.756h1.959a.93.93 0 00.908-.725 11.547 11.547 0 012.662-5.124.941.941 0 00.23-.688c-.178-2.247-1.018-3.633-1.91-5.103l-.231-.383c2.966-.126 5.376.525 7.014 1.88a.93.93 0 00.934.152 18.388 18.388 0 013.638-.96.93.93 0 10-.304-1.833 21.01 21.01 0 00-3.491.892c-1.717-1.233-4.641-2.41-9.45-1.848a.934.934 0 00-.714 1.36c.336.64.672 1.187.997 1.722.777 1.286 1.407 2.32 1.607 3.911A13.284 13.284 0 003.67 30.12H2.446C.982 30.119 0 31.169 0 32.718v5.827c0 1.974 1.869 1.974 2.488 1.974h1.917a9.087 9.087 0 004.61 4.568L8.01 49.748c-.108.5.016 1.02.336 1.418.36.428.891.67 1.45.661l5.144-.03a2.205 2.205 0 002.142-1.697l.447-2.157c2.464.35 4.965.35 7.428 0l.452 2.142a2.221 2.221 0 002.147 1.695l5.14.032a1.842 1.842 0 001.438-.651 1.7 1.7 0 00.347-1.413l-1.05-5.28c3.77-2.783 5.901-6.731 5.901-10.931v-.599a4.163 4.163 0 002.488.257 4.663 4.663 0 002.846-2.1 4.89 4.89 0 003.292-.147.935.935 0 00.489-1.228h-.001z" />
          <path d="M27.752 6.384a6.872 6.872 0 11-6.873 6.872v-.005a6.878 6.878 0 016.873-6.873v.006zm0 15.603a8.73 8.73 0 10-8.731-8.736 8.741 8.741 0 008.73 8.736h0z" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default React.memo(ReduceCosts);
```

Comment: If it works feel free to mark this as the answer and hit me with those imaginary internet points

Comment: Made those changes. Tried to use orange for fill and stroke. The SVG is blank now.

Comment: When you click on the `Run code snippet` button you can see the orange tho so you must be missing something. Make sure you copy the SVG right?!

Comment: Cool, your solution worked. However there is another way by setting colorInterpolationFilters="sRGB" on the feMatrix.